# convert regular compilation-mode output to inline view

Tags: flycheck, compilation-mode

It would be nice to show the info, warnings and errors from a regular `compilation-mode` buffer inline in the source code.

I checked to see if `flycheck` supports this but it appears no. Writing a custom backend would amount to re-writing the compilation mode regexp checkers, per language, which is sub-optimal, see https://www.flycheck.org/en/27/_downloads/flycheck.html#Syntax-checker-definitions

Has anybody written, or considered writing, a flycheck backend or independent minor mode that overlays `compilation-mode` information onto the source ? This might amount to a "Parsing structured output" backend for flycheck that would work for all languages that have a regular `compilation-mode`.